# Is polynomial coefficient map continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, continuity

Let $P_n$ be the vector space of all real polynomials with degree at most $n$. Define the inner product between two polynomials $p, q$ as

$$
\langle p, q \rangle = \int_0^1 p(x)q(x) \mathrm{d}x.
$$

Let $p_i$ denote the $i$th coefficient of a polynomial $p$. With respect to the above inner product, is the map $p \mapsto p_i$ a continuous map?

---

Note if we instead defined the inner product between two polynomials $p, q$ as

$$
\langle p, q \rangle = p_0q_0 + \dots + p_nq_n,
$$

then the map $p \mapsto p_i$ is continuous. This is because $1, x, \dots, x^n$ is an orthonormal basis of $P_n$ with respect to this inner product. By the Pythagorean theorem, we get

$$
\begin{aligned}
\|p - q\| &= \|(p_0 - q_0) + (p_1 - q_1)x + \dots + (p_n - q_n)x^n\| \\
& = \sqrt{(p_0 - q_0)^2 + (p_1 - q_1)^2 + \dots + (p_n - q_n)^2} \\
& \geq |p_i - q_i|.
\end{aligned}
$$

If $\|p - q\| < \varepsilon$, then $|p_i - q_i| < \varepsilon$, so $p \mapsto p_i$ is continuous. However, this doesn't work for the original inner product because $1, x, \dots, x^n$ is no longer an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Any linear functional on a finite dimensional normed linear space is continuous.